# Problema de codificación con BeautifulSoup ¿Cómo decodificar esto? -> (b'\xd1\x8e\xd1\x82\xd1\x83\xd0\xb1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, beautifulsoup

Estaba leyendo metadatos de una web con este código

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import argparse, sys


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--url", required=True, help="url to parser")
args = parser.parse_args()


webpage = request.urlopen( args.url )
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")


tag_str=""

for tag in soup.find_all("meta"):
 if tag.get("property", None) == "A:B:C":
  item = tag.get("content")
  tag_str+=item + ", "

print (tag_str)
```

Lo habia usado varias veces y funcionaba bíen, pero con una de las páginas me ha dado este error.

```
  File "C:\Users\ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 16-21: character maps to <undefined>
```

Una vez tuve un error parecido y lo sulucioné haciendo esto

```
try:
 tag_str = tag_str.decode('utf-8')
except AttributeError: pass
print (tag_str)
```

Pero esta vez no funcionó y tuve que hacer esto

```
print (tag_str.encode("utf-8"))
```

Y ahora funciona pero "tag_str" tiene  este formato

```
b'\xd1\x8e\xd1\x82\xd1\x83\xd0\xb1
```

¿Hay alguna forma de descodicar esto para que sea entendible por un ser humano?

Aunque realmente lo que me gustaría es que el código no falle. Me funciona bien el 99.99% de las veces sin tener que codificar y descodificar nada. Lo ideal es que funcionara el 100% de las veces. ¿Alguna idea para solucionar el problema?

Comment: La secuencia de bytes que te sale en `tag_str` es la codificación en UTF-8 de la cadena `"ютуб"`, que es "youtube" escrito en cirílico :-)

Comment: En algún momento tu código está intentando codificar un texto que le viene en Unicode usando la codificación cp1252. Posiblemente se trate del `print()` del final, si lo estás ejecutando en un entorno windows. El problema es que cp1252 es una codificación bastante limitada, en la que muchos caracteres Unicode no son representables, entre ellos los caracteres cirílicos

Comment: Osea que es ruso... mmm.. que problemón!! :-)  ¿Y cómo lo conseguirte decodificar? Me interesan los caractes aunque estén en ruso

Comment: Completando lo que comenta abulafia tag_str es en principio una cadena utf-8, si revertimos tu encoding (`b'\xd1\x8e\xd1\x82\xd1\x83\xd0\xb1'.decode("utf-8")`) obtenemos "ютуб". El problema es que la página de códigos que usas en tu terminal (CMD) no puede representar estos caracteres (cp1252).  Si cambias la página de códigos de la terminal a utf-8 por ejemplo antes de ejecutar el script: `chcp 65001` se debería imprimir sin problemas, la fuente también ha de soportarlo (como Lucida console).

Comment: Ok, así también funciona, lo acabo de probar... tenia el problema de que estaba redireccionando la salida del escript hacia un fichero desde un .bach con ">>" ... y  no sé por qué pero siguen escribiendose esos caracteres a pesar de que en el terminal se ven bien. Así que creo que voy a usar la solución del fichero que me dío abulafia.  Muchas Gracias @FJSevilla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posible reconstrucción de lo que ocurre:

La página que estas *raspando* contiene texto Unicode, en diferentes alfabetos y lenguajes (ya que en concreto la cadena que te ha dado problemas y que muestras en la pregunta corresponde al texto cirílico "ютуб", que significa "YouTube").

No hay problema con esto, ya que Python3 maneja nativamente cadenas Unicode, y BeautifulSoup parece que extrae la información sin problemas.

El problema lo tienes al final, cuando tratas de imprimir el resultado, ya que en ese momento Python tiene que convertir las cadenas de su representación interna Unicode, a una representación que tu terminal pueda manejar. Y en ese momento decide usar `cp1252` para ello (posiblemente estás ejecutando en Windows). Esta tabla de códigos está limitada a 256 posibles caracteres (menos en realidad) entre los que hay eñes, tildes, etc. pero no los caracteres cirílicos de ese tag, por lo que no puede hacer la conversión y "rompe".

Cuando le pides que lo convierta a UTF-8, no hay error, porque en ese formato es representable cualquier carácter Unicode, pero entonces es tu terminal la que no puede mostrar correctamente el resultado, porque posiblemente esta terminal sólo "entienda" cp1252.

Si en vez de volcarlo en la terminal lo vuelcas a un fichero, y después abres el fichero con algún editor que "entienda" utf-8, no tendrías ningún problema.

Si insistes en querer verlo en la terminal, ya que tu terminal no dispone de ciertos caracteres, puedes forzar a que la conversión sustituya esos caracteres por otros, en lugar de "romper". Naturalmente así no estarías viendo la verdadera cadena, sino una aproximación, por lo que yo preferiría la solución anterior en la que lo vuelcas a fichero y lo ves con un editor.

Tienes dos posibilidades:

1. Decirle que ignore cada carácter unicode que no pueda ser mostrado en cp1252. Simplemente ese carácter se lo salta. Puede ser útil si es una cadena larga con un solo caracter raro, por ejemplo `"Estю es una prueba"` se codificaría como `"Est es una prueba"`, saltándose el `"ю"` que no es representable. No obstante en tu cadena `"ютуб"` en la que todos son caracteres rusos, el resultado sería `""`, pues se los salta todos.
2. Decirle que sustituya cada carácter no representable por un `?`. En este caso tu cadena saldría como `????`.

El código necesario sería:

```
# Enfoque 1
print(tag_str.encode("cp1252", errors="ignore"))

# Enfoque 2
print(tag_str.encode("cp1252", errors="replace"))
```

La solución con fichero sería:

```
with open("resultados.txt", "wb") as f:
    f.write(tag_str.encode("utf-8"))
```

y después abrir `resultados.txt` en un editor compatible con UTF-8 (como Notepad++) para ver el resultado, incluyendo el texto en ruso.

Comment: Perfecto!! Funciona!! :-) Me quedo con la soción del fichero!! Muchísimas gracias @abulafia!!